# Не работает выданная роль с привилегиями для пользователя (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Создал роль, имеющая возможность использовать SELECT для одной таблицы. Затем был создан пользователь, которому была выдана роль. При использовании SHOW GRANTS все отображается корректно. Но при создании подключения от имени данного пользователя и использовании SELECT для соотв. таблицы выдается следующая ошибка: Error Code: 1142. SELECT command denied to user 'alex'@'localhost' for table 'user'.
Код создания роли и пользователя:

```
CREATE USER 'alex'@'localhost' identified BY 'Dn9iD*TN3$%_';
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS 'r_patient';
GRANT SELECT ON policlinica.user TO 'r_patient';
GRANT 'r_patient' TO 'alex'@'localhost';
```

Сама команда, используемая в другом подключении:

```
SELECT * FROM `policlinica`.`user`;
```

[image: Вывод команды SHOW GRANTS]

[image]

[image]

Comment: При выдаче пользователю возможности SELECT все работает, но простая выдача роли с такой же возможностью не работает

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - а какое значение у системной переменной `activate_all_roles_on_login`?

Answer (score 0):

Решением оказалось использование

```
SET DEFAULT ROLE 'role_name' TO 'user_name';
```

Comment: Не нравится мне это решение как-то... есть шанс, что юзеру ранее были назначены какие-то роли по умолчанию. А ведь SET DEFAULT ROLE не аддитивна и заменяет текущее значение - так что есть неиллюзорная вероятность этого юзера немножко поломать...